# "no migration to apply" message where there is some migrations to be applied

Tags: django, django-models

I have added a new field called "city" for my custom user model. I will run **makemigrations** and it create new file in migration folder:

```
migrations.AddField(
    model_name='customuser',
    name='city',
    field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, null=True, verbose_name='City'),
)
```

by running **migrate** it does migrate ok in *Windows*, and new field is going to be added to my table.

I do same thing in *Linux* command line; it creates same changes in new migration file  by running *makemigrations* but when 
I run **migrate** it tells me **no migration to apply**, and doesn't add new field to the table in database.

Previously I glossed over this issue and ended up creating new Database cause I am in development stage and it fixed the issue. However it is getting to the point that I need to find out what is going on, or find a workaround to actually force the changes somehow.

I have also tried the migrate **--fake-initial** but stills the issue persists.

I was wondering if anyone has seen this issue before and could please advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we run `python manage.py migrate` django sync our all app's migrations in `migrations-folder` with `django_migrations` model. If there exists a migration in `migration-folder` that is not part of `django_migrations` model entry then migrations applied to model. Whenever we are using same database table most likely this will applied once. So we need to check `django_migrations` weather our applied migrations already part of it or not. Even one can manually delete an entry from that which should not cause any problem in development environment. Not know about production development rule. Most likely not.